# OpenLayers zoom map to fit the div

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I've got a question concerning OpenLayers and OSM maps.

The general idea of the web application is to draw a route from some points. There are two cases:

1. Points for the route are given
2. There are no points for the route

What I want to do is to stretch the map to the div in which it is embedded (in order to provide kind of responsive design). I set the dimensions of the openlayers map to fit the div completely and there are no problems with it. In the case where I've got some points from which I draw the route I just draw the vector from them and then zoomToExtent to the drawn vector and works as I want it to work.
The problem occurs when there are no points given. When I do zoomToMaxExtent it just draws a small map in the middle of the div and the rest remains empty. What I want to obtain is to fill the whole div with the map. There is no problem for me if I will need to set some center point, but I do want to show as much map as it is only possible (for current resolution / window size). Do you know any ways to deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you need to setup a zoom falback, as the extend of no objects is 0 and OL willl fallback to a global zoom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am not sure if I understand what you mean. The idea of changing the extend if there are no objects is what I exactly want to achieve.
What do you mean by global zoom? That is probably what I am looking for.

Comment: I guess the definition of uoomToMaxExtend() for a vectorlayer is to get the bbox of all contained objects and calc an zoom+pan for the OL view that makes all of them visible. If there are no objects, it needs to use a 'best guess' of what might not be an unexpected result. I guess showing the whole world is currently implemented for that situtation.  
I suggest to add an if() clause to avoid trigger that method for empty layers and control the zoom/pan manually for that case.

Comment: or maybe just use the ZoomToExtent() avoiding the MAX extent problem. 
Also, you can tell your map explicitly, what are the min and max zoom levels at the point of init in [mapOptions](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Map) and thereby you can eliminate the "empty" zoomlevels of the map...  '{numZoomLevels: 5, minZoomLevel: 3, maxZoomLevel: 5}'